# Normalization issue in Java - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, normalization

I am gathering 10 acceleration values from an on-board accelerometer on a mobile device. I am then attempting to normalize these values between the range of -1,1. I am unable to figure out why this isn't working correctly.

Here is the normalization code:

```
class NormUtil {

private double dataHigh;
private double dataLow;
private double normalizedHigh;
private double normalizedLow;

 public NormUtil(double dataHigh, double dataLow) {
     this(dataHigh, dataLow, 1, -1);
 }

 public NormUtil(double dataHigh, double dataLow, double normalizedHigh, double normalizedLow) {
    this.dataHigh = dataHigh;
    this.dataLow = dataLow;
    this.normalizedHigh = normalizedHigh;
    this.normalizedLow = normalizedLow;
}

public double normalize(double e) {
    return ((e - dataLow)
                    / (dataHigh - dataLow))
                    * (normalizedHigh - normalizedLow) + normalizedLow;
}
```

On a button press, the highest/lowest acceleration values are found in this code:

```
            A = enrolAcc.get(0);
            B = enrolAcc.get(0);
            for (Float i: enrolAcc) {
                if(i < A) A = i;
                if(i > B) B = i;
            }
```

Once the highest/lowest values are found a NormUtil instance is created and this instance is used to normalize the array of acceleration values and then add the normalized values to a new array:

```
            NormUtil norm = new NormUtil(B,A,1,-1);

            for(int j = 0; j < enrolAcc.size(); j++) {
                double start = enrolAcc.get(j);
                double x = norm.normalize(start);
                nAcc[j] = x;
            }
```

This nAcc array is then put into a string array and then a single string to display in a text view. The issue is the text view is always initialized with the original non-normalized acceleration values, here is the code I use for that:

```
            String normD[] = new String[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                normD[i] = String.valueOf(nAcc[i]);
            }

            StringBuilder strBuilder2 = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i<normD.length; i++) {
                strBuilder2.append(normD[i] + ",");
            }
            normData = strBuilder.toString();

            textNorm.setText("Normalised: " + normData);
```

So my question is, where am I going wrong with adding the normalized values to the normalized array and is this normalization method correct for what I am trying to achieve? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should read the Normalization tag, I don't think it's what you're trying to do.